# How to make a library management system?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to create a library management system which is supposed to be used to store/keep info about the library and it's members (book title, author, name, borrower's picture and other stuffs).

The app has 6 buttons : delete, save, add, previsous, next and upload (to upload
pictures).

The app is working correctly on my computer which is a developing machine but when I try to install the app on another computer after packaging it, it fails to save the new record including the picture.

I am using Microsoft Access as datasource.

Here is the code for the save button.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to have forgot to post your code. Please also tell us what error(s) you're getting.

Comment: I believe you might have forgot to install your database alongside of the program but we will need you to post the information for you forgot in order to give a concrete answer

Comment: Another potential issue is that your database may not be on the same relative or absolute path on the production computer than on the development computer.